# Смена картинок в delphi

Tags: delphi

Доброго дня. Мне нужно реализовать смену картинок без "рывка". Я пользуюсь таким циклом:

Код Delphi

```
case attempt of
 1: att_im.Picture:=attempt1.Picture;
 2: att_im.Picture:=attempt2.Picture;
 3: att_im.Picture:=attempt3.Picture;
 4: att_im.Picture:=attempt4.Picture;
 5: att_im.Picture:=attempt5.Picture;
 6: att_im.Picture:=attempt6.Picture;
end
```

но при смене картинок в 70% случаях идет какое-то поддергивание и форму на несколько милисекунд моргает. Чем это может быть связано? И можно ли как-нибудь по-другому заменить картинки, кроме как их перетаскивать с места на место.

Comment: Чуть больше информации. Что такое `att_im`?

Comment: att_im - главная картинка, которую заменяют все остальные изображения в случае проигрыша

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Как бы решал данный вопрос я:**

У вас есть некоторый набор картинок *(видимо, на каждый вид `Attempt'а`)* и должен быть компонент, который умеет показывать **одну** нужную картинку.

Для таких целей совершенно необязательно создавать по компоненту на каждую возможную картинку. *Тем более, представьте себе, что вы будете делать если ваше количество картинок увеличится до 200?* Швырять на форму 200 компонентов?

---

Заведите массив объектов типа `TPicture` - `attemptPictures : Array[...] of TPicture` и загрузите их все из соответствующих файлов или ресурсов. Далее, просто подменяйте на компоненте типа `TImage` *(который один на форму)* его поле `TPicture` на нужное вам.

---

*В случае, если артефакты при перерисовке сохранятся, то могу попробовать помочь как-нибудь еще.*

Comment: Добавлю, что проблема возникает из-за особенностей работы данных компонентов, они перерисовывают все дважды. Могу посоветовать копировать через буфер данные, а не просто подменять TPicture. Например функцией

    bitblt(source.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height,
        destination.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

Затем не забыть сделать перерисовку.

Comment: Огромное спасибо всем, сегодня днем попробую сделать и обязательно отпишусь!

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, это проблема называется неправильной буферизацией. Точнее её отсутствием.

Например тут http://www.delphimaster.ru/cgi-bin/forum.pl?id=1406033011&n=0 довольно подробно обсуждают эту тему.

Тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/318876/ статья с примерами кода (Там для примера можно рассмотреть компонент TEsLayout — прозрачный Layout с возможностью буферизации вложенных в него TGraphicControl-ов).

Тема эта старая, но в компании-призводителе проблему так и не решили.